# Plotly: Show hoverinfo in treemap only for child nodes

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, treemap, plotly-python

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({'world':['world']*4,
                   'continent':['SA','SA','NA','NA'],
                  'country':['Brazil','Uruguay','USA','Canada'],
                  'total_cases_per_100':[6,1,12,8]})

fig = px.treemap(df, path=['world','continent','country'],values='total_cases_per_100')
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate=None, hoverinfo='value')
```

The code above gives the following output-

[image]

As visible, it displays correctly the value of `total_cases_per_100` for `USA` and all the other child nodes. But for parent nodes, it sums it up, which is wrong as `total_cases_per_100` is a ratio and not a total.

Is there anyway I can hide the `value` hoverinfo for all nodes except the children?

In case this is not possible, the actual value for the parent nodes is also available with me but I am not sure how I could replace the generated value with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `hover_data` / `customdata` and override values for none leaf nodes.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px


df = pd.DataFrame({'world':['world']*4,
                   'continent':['SA','SA','NA','NA'],
                  'country':['Brazil','Uruguay','USA','Canada'],
                  'total_cases_per_100':[6,1,12,8]})
leaves = df.select_dtypes("object").apply("/".join, axis=1).values


fig = px.treemap(df, path=['world','continent','country'],values='total_cases_per_100', hover_data=["total_cases_per_100"])
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate='%{customdata[0]}')
fig.data[0].customdata = [
    v if fig.data[0].ids[i]
    in leaves else [""]
    for i, v in enumerate(fig.data[0].customdata)
]
fig
```

Comment: Being able to manipulate `ids` this way opens up a lot of customization options, thanks! I don't suppose there would be a way to hide that little hover arrow on parent nodes?

Comment: I couldn't find anyway to prevent hover box appearing.  However I quite liked the visual queue to where the hover focus is ....

Comment: It also highlights the node which brings focus to it. But anyway, I was only asking out of curiosity. I am anyway substituting it for other values.